# Apache vhost перенаправить на страницу

Tags: apache2.4

Привет,
на мой сервер указывают два домена dom1 и dom2.

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при запросе по dom1 - все работало штатно,
а при запросе по dom2 шло перенаправление на dom1/hi.php.

Мой конфиг:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs"
    ServerName dom1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dom2
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* http://dom1/hi.php [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Сейчас перенаправление идет только если после dom2/...  есть символы.
Если запросить http://dom2 - то будет выдана ошибка запроса.

Как сделать, даже если нет символов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю что если в вашем варианте заменить следующую строку

```
RewriteRule .* http://dom1/hi.php [R]
```

на

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dom1/hi.php [R]
```

Хотя по сути и ваш вариант должен был работать.

Только вот данные после слеша будут потеряны.Если хотите передать их по другому `url` то так:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dom1/hi.php$1 [R]
```

Эти круглые скобки они как значения переменной.Их можно получить через оператор `$n`, где буква `n` это число показывающее какую круглую скобку(значение попадающее под это выражение) по счету взять.

URL на подобии этого `dom2/aaa/bbb/ccc`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://dom1/hi.php$1 [R]
```

после `RewriteRule ...` перенаправится нa `http://dom1/hi.php/aaa`.
если надо передать `bbb` то берем вторые круглые скобки,то есть `$2`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://dom1/hi.php$2 [R]
```

И по аналогии.

**Мои предложения:**

Вы можете использовать директиву RedirectMatch, чтобы заставить Apache отправлять пользователя куда то еще:

**Вариант 1:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dom2
    RewriteEngine On
    RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://dom1/hi.php$1
</VirtualHost>
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName dom2
    ServerAlias www.dom2

    RedirectPermanent / http://dom1/hi.php

    ServerAdmin admin@redirectedurl.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

См. Следующее:

[RedirectMatch Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

[HTTP status codes 3xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx)

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domen2
    Redirect / "http://domen1/daily.php"
</VirtualHost> Это сработало, но и ваше тоже правильно, оказалось - браузер кеш выдавал))

Comment: Чем символ начала строки помогает?