# Htaccess в сайте

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Я бы хотел спросить что надо для безопасности и вообще что надо для сайта моего у меня `index.php contact.php contactome.php` все `php` у меня такой код чтобы `.php` скрыть:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Вот а я хочу не только скрыть вот например поменять `www.domain.com/index` на `www.domain.com/home` но файл у меня главной страницы это `index.php` а вот мне обьяснить кто то может что такое вообще `.htaccess` и что можно делать с ним буду блогадарен!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/664833/207445 Смотреть 9 пункт  "На уровне .htaccess".

Comment: А .htaccess это файл где прописываются настройки для сервера.Эти настройки можно прописать и в конфигурационном файле сервера,только надо его перезагрузить чтоб условия действовали .А с помощью `.htaccess`  restart server не нужен.

Comment: Понятно для чего htaccess нужен а как поменять www.domain.com/index на www.domain.com/чтото?

Comment: как поменять dom1 на domen2 ?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/673497/207445

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- site

  - home

    - index.php
  - call

    - index.php
- admin
- vendor

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Файл .htaccess это файл для конфигурации той папки, в которой он находится. Для того чтоб изменить стандартную страницу index.php на home.php, добавьте строчку в файле .htaccess`DirectoryIndex home.php`

```
# Запускаем движок замены
RewriteEngine on
# Если запрашиваемый объект не папка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# если запрашиваемый объект с дописанным расширением php - файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# делаем замену с дописыванием .php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: вы меня не правильно поняли вот например есть contact.php  я хочу чтоб было на url /call например

Comment: Вот да у меня тоже так скрывает концовку это спасибо понятно вот у меня www.domain.com/contact/ contact.php имя файла этот код скрывает только .php а я хочу не только скрыть   переименовать contact на call например